# Golang panic: runtime error: index out of range only happens when run outside debugger

Tags: go, indexoutofrangeexception

I have the following code used to find two integers that sum to a given total in a given slice:

```
type Store_object struct {
    C      int
    I      int
    Prices []int
}
//..other unrelated functions...

func FindItemPairs(scenarios []Store_object) ([]string, error) {
    var results []string
    for scIndex := 0; scIndex < len(scenarios); scIndex++ {
        scenario := scenarios[scIndex]
        for prIndex := 0; prIndex < len(scenario.Prices); prIndex++ { //<--!sc
            firstItem := scenario.Prices[prIndex]
            if firstItem >= scenario.C {
                continue
            }
            for cmpIndex := prIndex + 1; cmpIndex < len(scenario.Prices); cmpIndex++ {
                secondItem := scenario.Prices[cmpIndex]

                switch {
                case secondItem >= scenario.C:
                    continue
                case firstItem+secondItem == scenario.C:
                    result := "Case #" + strconv.Itoa(scIndex+1) +
                        " " + strconv.Itoa(firstItem) + " " +
                        strconv.Itoa(secondItem)
                    results = append(results, result)
                }
            }
        }
   }
   return results, nil
}
```

however, when I attempt to run my code to find the item pairs, I get the following error:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
   <store_credit>.FindItemPairs(0x208208000, 0x1e, 0x20, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
<store_credit_location>.go:76 +0x4ac 
main.main()
    <main_dir>/test_sc.go:16 +0x24d
exit status 2
```

(relevant line is noted with <--!sc above  and <--!main below)

In order to try to debug, I used the following project https://github.com/mailgun/godebug to test, and found that my code executed without issue.

I currently have no clue how I would be accessing a value that is out-of-range, but have no idea how I will debug this further...

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

For more context, here is the code jam I'm trying to implement: https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/351101/dashboard#s=p0

Edit: For even more context, here is the main file I am running that calls this function:

```
func main() {
    cases, err := store_credit.ReadLines("A-small-practice.in")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(cases)

    results, err := store_credit.FindItemPairs(cases) //<--!main
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(results); i++ {
        fmt.Println(results[i])
    }
}
```

ReadLines works fine with no issues.

Comment: Is this the only goroutine that can be accessing `scenarios`, or any of it's items at the time of panic?

Comment: Are you sure line 76 is marked with `<--!`? I would expect an out of range on either the line before or after, but not the `for` line.

Comment: @captncraig 
Comment 1: I'm pretty sure, since I'm not attempting to spawn any goroutines. I'm importing this code and calling that function from another source file (my main source), but my main function shouldn't be accessing any of its internal variables.

Comment 2: that's the line it's telling me about whenever I run it. I'm as confused as you are on that front.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that you may have a data race somewhere. Try running it with the -race flag.

> go run -race myfile.go

Comment: Okay, so adding this flag lets it run without issues (like running it in the debugger) but I'm still not sure where the source of the issue is... Sorry, I'm new to Go, so I'm still learning how to properly debug it. I've looked into the -run docs and there's no warnings shown when I run with -race, it just seems to work.